# Please help me understand this query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm reading SQL Antipatterns and found this query really hard to understand:

```
SELECT
    bp1.product_id, b1.date_reported AS latest, b1.bug_id 
FROM
    Bugs b1
    JOIN 
    BugsProducts bp1 ON (b1.bug_id = bp1.bug_id) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
      Bugs AS b2
      JOIN 
      BugsProducts AS bp2 ON b2.bug_id = bp2.bug_id
    )
     ON bp1.product_id = bp2.product_id AND 
         (b1.date_reported < b2.date_reported OR b1.date_reported = b2.date_reported
          AND
          b1.bug_id < b2.bug_id
         )
WHERE
    b2.bug_id IS NULL;
```

Please explain this to me SQL experts.. Thank you!

Comment: Very weird having the `b2.bug_id IS NULL` alongside the condition with the less than on the same field `b1.bug_id < b2.bug_id`.

Comment: That's why it's an antipattern :-)

Comment: @johan this sql query is actually a recommendation in the antipattern book.

Comment: @Kevin Lee: a good one or a bad one?

Comment: @Orbling: Why? the JOIN condition is "where internal key is greater for the right table". But it's an outer join so IS NULL says "where you didn't find a right table row". Can you explain more why you think this please.

Comment: @gbn a good one. the author suggests to use this join query when the scalability of the query over large data sets of data is important. and it scales better than a subquery solution.

Comment: @Kevin Lee: generally, the EXISTs (did author mean a subquery in an EXISTS?) is normally safer and more correct across most RDBMS. As per Johan's answer

Comment: It just looks confusing to me; that is what antipatterns are all about right? code that works, but is hard to grok for humans, or brittle or .... The fact `that it works` is an antipatterns only redeeming quality.

Answer (score 2):

Show me bug/products where there are no later bugs, based on date/id

You can simplify the code to pseudo code

```
SELECT
    pair1 data
FROM
    pair1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    pair2
     ON same product, 1st date <= 2nd date, 1st internal id <= 2nd internal id
WHERE
    no such pair2
```

Edit, FYI: the author is SO user Bill Karwin https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860

Comment: that leaves the antipattern in place, you are using a join to filter stuff. Joins are for joining, where is for filtering. That's why it's so confusing.

Comment: @Johan: Disagree. You can JOIN on LIKE, <=, BETWEEN, etc. It capture the condition that relate the 2 tabl. I'd use an EXISTS or EXCEPT normally of course. And see question comments.. it's a *good* pattern...

Comment: @Johan Inner join is for filtering, nothing wrong with this query. Inner join basically says 'Remove the left side when nothing is found on the right side'. That is filtering.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the query in the question is the `good` pattern. I find it confusing and would rewrite it as:

```
SELECT
    bp1.product_id, b1.date_reported AS latest, b1.bug_id 
FROM Bugs b1
INNER JOIN BugsProducts bp1 ON (b1.bug_id = bp1.bug_id) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * FROM Bugs AS b2
  INNER JOIN BugsProducts AS bp2 ON (b2.bug_id = bp2.bug_id)
  WHERE (bp1.product_id = bp2.product_id) 
     AND 
     (
        (b1.date_reported < b2.date_reported) OR 
        (b1.date_reported = b2.date_reported AND b1.bug_id < b2.bug_id)
     )
```

I strongly suspect that this code has the same performance (on MySQL anyway) as the query in the question.

**Just in case people are wondering:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

> *Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference*

What was the antipattern associated with this 'good' pattern anyway, would really like to know.

Comment: The SQL is good pattern in the book (I agree). EXISTS is more correct of course. However the JOIN condition in this case captures the relationship between the two table pairs. Do you advocate having on simple = conditions in a JOIN then? Finally, SELECT 1 in an EXISTS is an antipattern in itself almost, or at least a superstition. So -1 overall despite giving EXISTs.

Comment: Probably overlapped. To show the superstition compare * or 1/0 or log(-1) in the exists. There is zero value using a column